# Android sqlite, set row position for a new column

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, sql-update

I have added a new columnt (`position`) to the table. It needs to be ordered from 0 to n. And should reflect the order of rows by `_id`. But the thing is that `_id` has gaps, because some rows were deleted, and `position` shouldn't have gaps.

Like this:

```
_id   position[new column]
1     0 
4     1   
8     2
17    3
```

How can I achive this during the upgrade of the database? It would be great to have only one sql statement to perform with `execSQL`, without need to query existing data with cursors.

Comment: i am not understand your question i think you want to add one column at data migration time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other DBMS have `ROW_NUMBER()` to make this easier.

In SQLite you can use a correlated sub query to count "how many rows have a lower id than this one".  The answer to which happens to exactly match the enumerator column you want *(`position`)*.

```
UPDATE
  yourTable
SET
  position = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM yourTable   lookup
               WHERE lookup._id < yourTable._id
             )
```

Comment: Looks like perfect.

Comment: It works perfectly!
You have saved lots of my time.
I've tried something like this:
UPDATE yourTable SET position = ((SELECT MAX(position) FROM yourTable) + 1) ORDER BY _id LIMIT -1
But it seems Android doesn't support SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT

Comment: Aim to not write SQL that relies on the order that records are read or written.  Counting based on `_id` works even if the engine writes the records in reverse.